# "Dependence" vs. "dependency"

Tags: differences, nouns

These are two words that have baffled me for long. *Dependency* is given as 'excessive dependence' in Chambers, but I would love to know how the spoken usage is. My guess is *dependency* has a political touch to it. In addition, there is an *independency* as well in the dictionaries, though it does not sound popular.

Comment: Same question is here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41528/differences-between-dependence-and-dependency, with much better discussion

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think "dependence" and "dependency" are like "competence" and "competency". Both are nouns. Yet, "dependence" emphasizes the **quality** of being dependent. So, it may also be **abstract**. Whereas, "dependency" focuses on the **state** of being dependent. It is likely to be **concrete**.

Comment: Much better - deeper and thoughtful - answer is here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/41561/19905

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between quality and state.