# Independence vs. Independency

Tags: meaning, nouns

Most often used is "*independence*" as far as I know, however what is the difference?

I only found a question about ["dependence vs. dependency"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57080/dependence-vs-dependency) where is said that "*dependence*" describes the quality (also abstract) and "*dependency*" describes the state. Is this the same for the opposites? It was mentioned in the original question, but not answered.

Comment: [Independence: the fact or state of being independent.] [Independency: (rare) an indipendent state (archaic term for indipendence).] Reference: Oxford Dictionary of English

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would almost always use *independence* where many historical writers might have used *independency*.  One is example is the ["American Declaration of Independency"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SB49AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA361&dq=%22independency%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qznBT8nOO8f28gOitoisAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22independency%22&f=false) reported in *The Gentleman's Magazine* in London in August 1776.

The example where I might use *[Independency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_%28religion%29)* is as a form of church government compared with *Episcopacy* and *Presbyterianism*, but even then I might use *[Congregationalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congregationalist_polity)* instead.

I don't think I have such problems with using *dependency* or *interdependency*.

Answer (score 3):

This is more worthy of a comment (I don't have enough reputation), but in the math / statistics community, **independency** gets an inordinate amount of use.

On their own, Google shows that the **"Independence"** keyword is used [~500x more frequently](http://www.googlebattle.com/?domain=%22independence%22&domain2=%22independency%22&submit=Go%21) than its archaic counterpart. However, when you add the keywords **"Math"** and **"Statistics"**, it is only used [~50x more frequently](http://www.googlebattle.com/?domain=%22math%22%20%22statistics%22%20%22independence%22&domain2=%22math%22%20%22statistics%22%20%22independency%22&submit=Go%21). In fact, nearly 50% of the references to **"Independency"** also contain "Math" and "Statistics".

In this context, we often see **independence** used as a possessed quality, and **independency** used *independently* of possession:

- We can verify the linear **independence** of x and y.
- Every **independency** contributes to the sparsity of the problem.

Even in this field, they are often used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in one way, **independency** can be used wherever **dependency** can be used to serve as its antonym. For example:

He suffers from serious alcohol dependency.

He enjoys complete alcohol independency.

Comment: "He enjoys complete alcohol independency." is poor English, and would probably not even be understood. It would more likely be interpreted as saying that he is a teetotaler.